# Combine values of inner object using JavaScript or Underscore

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, underscore.js

I have an array as follows:

```
const arr = [{
  name: 'XYZ',
  values: [1, 2, 3]
}, {
  name: 'ABC',
  values: [5]
}, {
  name: 'XYZ',
  values: [4, 5, 6]
}, {
  name: 'ABC',
  values: [8, 9]
}];
```

I'm using underscore js and trying to transform as follows:

```
const result = [{
  name: 'XYZ',
  values: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
}, {
  name: 'ABC',
  values: [5, 8, 9]
}]
```

I was able to group by `name` and trying to loop in, but not sure how do I merge `values`. So far this is what I've done:

```
_.chain(arr)
  .groupBy((item) => item.name)
  // I don't know what to do here
  .value();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ES6, you can use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce?v=b) with a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to get the desired result:

```js
const arr = [{"name":"XYZ","values":[1,2,3]},{"name":"ABC","values":[5]},{"name":"XYZ","values":[4,5,6]},{"name":"ABC","values":[8,9]}];

const result = [...arr.reduce((m, { name, values }) => {
  const el = m.get(name) || { name, values: [] }; // get the result object from the map or create a new one
  
  el.values.push(...values); // push the current values to the result object values property

  return m.set(name, el); // add the result object to the map, and return the map
}, new Map()).values()]; // get the map values, and spread to an array

console.log(result);
```

Using underscore:

```js
const arr = [{"name":"XYZ","values":[1,2,3]},{"name":"ABC","values":[5]},{"name":"XYZ","values":[4,5,6]},{"name":"ABC","values":[8,9]}];

const result = _.chain(arr)
  .groupBy('name') // group by name
  .mapObject((group, name) => ({ // map each group to a new object
    name,
    values: _.flatten(_.pluck(group, 'values')) // get all values arrays, and flatten to a single array
  }))
  .values() // convert the groups object to an array
  .value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great, I'm able to understand the underscore part. It would be great if you can explain the ES6 part.

Comment: See update. Note that to understand the ES6 solution, you'll have to read about Map, Array#reduce, and spread syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can try vanilla Javascript way.

```
var result = [];
arr.forEach((item) => {
    let currObj = result.find((item2) => item2.name === item.name);
    if(currObj){
      currObj.values = currObj.values.concat(item.values);
    } else {
      result.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item)));
    }
})
```